# Looker Studio display double conversion

Tags: looker-studio

The Looker Studio display double conversion from Google Ads. It shows the all conversions from the account so the Google Ads conversions(primary) and the GA4 conversions(secondary) together. How to set up to show only the Google Ads conversions?